# Народ - имя собирательное?

Tags: части-речи

Здравствуйте! Слово "народ" - это имя собирательное?

Comment: А Вы, вообще, что-то о знаках препинания слышали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что слово "народ" может выступать в качестве собирательного. Это одно из значений слова, как правило, разг.

*"Народ повалил из зала"* - ведь речь идет о группе людей, находившихся в зале, а не о всей нации.

Comment: Спасибо,не вижу разницы между словами "молодежь" и "народ".

Comment: в этом значении - да

Comment: А, да. В этом значении - может быть собирательным. Я не подумал. 
Но это все-таки не основное значение, поэтому моя (и не только) ошибка объяснима.
Зато - вот и пример "тонкого случая", когда само правило об отсутствии множественного числа у собирательных надо применять с осторожностью.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, народ - это имя существительное. *Собирательные существительные*, по БСЭ - это

> существительные, обозначающие совокупность лиц, предметов, явлений как единство, как одно неделимое целое, например «родня», «молодёжь», «студенчество», «дичь», «бельё». С. с. не могут употребляться во множественном числе или в сочетании с количественными числительными (в отличие от существительных, обозначающих совокупность отдельных однородных предметов, людей и т.д., например «группа», «стая»).

*Пять народов, Многие народы*. Так как множественное число возможно, то народ не собирательное существительное.

Comment: спасибо за ответ,а духи это имя собирательное?

Answer (score 3):

[[@Student](/users/1870/student)](/users/1870/student), Если вы хотите разобраться и понять, а не просто получить ответ, посмотрите на значение. Собирательность означает все предметы или всех людей с общим признаком, выраженным сами существительным, т.е. в этом случае *собирает* свои элементы. Профессура - всех профессоров, картофель - всю картошку и проч. И именно поэтому как правила не имеет множественного числа - оно само означает множество.
"Народ", если что-то и собирает, то людей, но не всех, а каких-то, по дополнительному признаку выделенных. Что касается духОв, то тут и собирать-то нечего.

В отношение самого множественного числа как признака собирательности, то это дейстивильно хороший признак, но не универсальный, есть несколько спорных случаев, когда существительное множественного числа по смыслу оставаясь собирательным (макароны, например, - собрание "макаронин"). Во всяком случае представление о единственности и множественности не раскрывает сути понятия, возможно поэтому Вы и путаетесь.

И еще. Собирательные существительные - все равно существительные. Ставить вопрос "собирательное или существительное" - неверно.
Нет такого понятия в грамматике как "имя собирательное", есть "собирательные существительные" - один из разрядов части речи "имя существительное".

Comment: спасибо за ответ ,а разве имя не охватывает имена существительные?

Comment: и как понять то ,что народ не собирает всех людей,по-моему всех собирает?

Comment: Не всех. Только тех, кто к народу относится. Т.е. "народ" не собирает, а скорее выделяет из множества. 
Еще раз. Профессура - все профессора. Картофель - вся картошка. 
А народ - не все люди, а только в пределах какого-то множества, страны.
Бывают разные народы. Поэтому у слова "народ" и есть множественное число.    
   
А вот "человечество" действительно собирает всех людей ("человеков"). Зверьё - всех зверей. Бельё - все бельё (тут иначе не скажешь). Богема - всех артистов.

Уточнил в комментрарии к ответу yupaz.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Причем здесь разные народы ,я же не говорю пришел один народ и ушел другой народ, например в предложении наш народ переживает трудные времена ,разве слово "народ"  не является собирательным существительным?

Comment: >например в предложении наш народ переживает трудные времена ,разве слово "народ" не является собирательным существительным?  
  
Нет, здесь вряд ли. Собирательным может быть в значениях "толпа" или "простонародье". Вряд ли под "народом" в этой фразе понимается что-то подобное. У вас же без особых грамматических проблем можно сказать "наши народы переживают трудные времена" имея в виду народ несколько стран.

Answer (score 2):

НАРОД ни в одном из значений в современной лингвистике не является собирательным.Раньше отдельные учёные включали его в список собирательных как совокупность людей(Гвоздев).

Наш народ переживает трудные времена - конкретное, обозначающее сообщество "наших" людей, а есть другое сообщество - болгарский народ, трудящийся народ, простой народ.

Народ повалил из зала - в значении "толпа".Это тоже не собирательное.
Слова типа стая, стадо, толпа, полк, оркестр, коллектив и др. по значению близки к собирательным, так как обозначают совокупность предметов, а по грамматическим показателям являются конкретными (изменяются по числам, сочетаются с количественными числительными).Вот Шанский объясняет:

<…> Нередко к собирательным существительным относят также и слова
вроде куча, груда, созвездие, полк, труппа, комиссия, стая и т.п., однако это
неверно: 1. В отличие от собирательных существительных эти слова обозначают такую совокупность, которая не имеет в себе никакого выраженного в
языковых формах оттенка множественности.
    2. В отличие от собирательных существительных эти слова свободно образуют формы множественного числа (ср. кучи, груды, созвездия, полки и
т.д.).
    3. В отличие от собирательных существительных эти слова могут
определяться не только неопределённо-количественными словами и
дробными числительными, но и числительными количественными (две
кучи, три комиссии, тридцать пять групп и т.д.) (Н.М.Шанский. Современный русский язык / Под ред. Е.М. Галкиной-Федорук. М., 1964).

У Костомарова: на вопрос о том, что такое, например, «мебель», можно дать ответ с помощью перечисления различных объектов (мебель – это столы, стулья, диваны, кровати, шкафы…), объединяемых по одному общему для всех этих объектов качеству, по одному признаку – все они служат для создания в помещении комфортной для человека обстановки. (Ср. также: посуда – это чашки, тарелки, кастрюли, котелки…;обувь – это туфли, ботинки, валенки, тапки…; зелень – это укроп, петрушка, сельдерей, лук…). Но, отвечая на вопрос о том, что такое «толпа», мы не станем перечислять: *«толпа – это учителя, врачи, дворники, продавцы…» Мы ответим: это большое количество собравшихся вместе людей.Слова типа толпа, полк, стадо не предполагают зарождения нового качества; они называют такое множество предметов или лиц, которое не объединяется какой-то качественно новой характеристикой. Поэтому мы и считаем, что рассматриваемые слова целесообразно признать конкретными, ср.: солдат – солдаты, полк солдат; лошадь – лошади, табун лошадей. Значимым остаётся и то, что слова типа толпа, стадо, полк, отряд называют «такие совокупности, которые имеют место наряду с другими такими же совокупностями, а потому могут быть сосчитанными» [Современный русский литературный язык / под ред. В. Г. Костомарова и В. И. Максимова. М., 2003. С. 371].

Comment: спасибо ,объясните как понять это предложение ( у собирательных существительных с тем же количественным значением: много народу (ср.: история народа); всякого сброду понаехало)Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П. §152. Окончания родительного падежа единственного числа существительных мужского рода -а(-я) – -у(-ю) http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm

Comment: А вот это как раз ЛЕКСИЧЕСКОЕ (а не грамматическое)значение собирательности  Лексически значение собирательности может быть выражено единственным числом конкретных существительных: Вся вишня цвела(имеется в виду не отдельное дерево, а весь вид) Бекас полетел (все бекасы как род)http://lik-bez.com/board/morfologija/sushhestvitelnoe/razrjady_sushhestvitelnykh_po_znacheniju/31-1-0-46

Comment: Когда разбирают такие существительные, то пишут "конкретное в значении собирательного" - переходный случай.

Comment: спасибо,выходит так,что несколько параграфов Розенталь говорит о существительных (собирательных отвлеченных и так далее) лексического значения?

Comment: >НАРОД ни в одном из значений в современной лингвистике не является собирательным.   

Людмила, простите, но в значении "простонародье" - даже не сомневайтесь. Аналог дворянству, купечеству или там мещанству. И если "Народники пошли в народ" - это то тут всё равно собирательное.  

С толпой - да, еще можно трактовать по-разному, хотя в основном понимании это значение ничего общего с группой или стаей не имеет. Стая или группа выделяется по признаку принадлежности к конкретной стае. А как можно принадлежать к конкретной толпе? Или как можно сосчитать толпу? Не, что-то перемудрили тут классики.

Comment: Короче, предвижу, что спор опять упрется в дефиниции. Если четко определить, что такое "собирательное существительное", то половина вопросов отпадет сама собой. А если посмотреть, что под этим термином понимают разные авторы - то и вторая половина скорее всего рассосется.

Comment: behemothus, во-первых,запросто можно сказать, что к выходу побежала толпа деревенских, а к сцене-толпа курсантов, а третья толпа затеяла драку в центре зала.Во-вторых,о дефинициях - я же сказала, что некоторые учёные называют их собирательными, основываясь на лексическом значении, но сейчас принято говорить"конкретное сущ. со знач. собирательности".В-третьих,уважаемому Студенту вовсе не нужны наши ответы, ему надо нас раззадорить всего-навсего.Не поняла, правда, зачем ему это и при чём здесь "духи" - бесспорное вещественное.Заметили, он ни одного ответа так и не принял?

Comment: только что зарегистрировался и не знаю как принимать ответы,подскажите,пожалуйста...а ответ мне очень нужен, никак не могу понять почему в арабском и в английском ученые доказывают ,что это  собирательное существительное ,а в русском нет ,вроде бы одно и тоже.а также ученые арабисты ,например Гранде говорит ,что слово "народ" в арабском собирательное существительное,правда,он называет его именем собирательным... а слепо следовать правилам, не считаю правильным. спасибо всем!!

Answer (score 0):

Если народ - имя собирательное, тогда дверь - имя прилагательное.